# Komma vor "und" bei Aufzählungen mit Mehrdeutigkeit

Tags: punctuation, list

Die Regeln sind erstmal eindeutig. Es wird bei Aufzählungen ein Komma gesetzt, wenn denn dann nicht ein *und*, *oder*, etc. verwendet wird. <sup>[DUDEN](https://web.archive.org/web/20120624182819/http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma)</sup>

> Ich aß einen Apfel, eine Birne und eine Banane.

Die vollständigen Regeln kann man auch auf [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html?MenuId=OfficialSpelling143) nachlesen.

Generell gilt, vor einem *und* steht kein Komma. Es gibt aber Ausnahmen:

1. Ein Nebensatz, Zusatz oder Nachtrag wird mit Komma getrennt, **auch** vor einem *und*.

   > Er sagte, dass er morgen komme, und verabschiedete sich.
   >
   > Mein Onkel, ein großer Tierfreund, und seine Katzen leben in einer alten Mühle.
   >
   > Sie fragte: „Brauchen Sie die Unterlagen?“, und öffnete die Schublade.
2. Selbstständige Sätze, die mit *und* verbunden werden **können** durch ein Komma zusätzlich getrennt werden.

   > Er aß nur das Brot, und den Kuchen ließ er stehen.

Wozu ich aber keine Quelle finde, ist, wie man es bei Aufzählungen handhabt, in denen eine Zweideutigkeit entsteht.

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, Maria und Peter.

Ich weiß, dass im Englischen ein Komma vor *und* optional ist und somit hier problemlos gesetzt werden kann, sogar gesetzt werden sollte, um Missverständnisse auszuschließen. Aber wie sieht es im Deutschen aus? Kann ich hier ebenfalls ein Komma setzen oder muss ich den Satz umformulieren, um Missverständnisse garantiert zu vermeiden?

> 1. Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, Maria, und Peter.
> 2. Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, sowie Maria und Peter.
> 3. Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, meiner Mutter Maria und meinem Vater Peter.

Comment: Mir fällt dabei auf, dass der Satz *Mein Onkel, ein großer Tierfreund, und seine Katzen leben in einer alten Mühle.* durchaus auch 2x gelesen werden muss, um ihn nicht mehrdeutig zu verstehen ;p

Comment: Wohl wahr. Derartige Sätze hören sich ziemlich konstruiert an und würden wegen solcher „Holprigkeiten“ in der Praxis kaum verwendet werden.

Comment: Ich würde die Kommata bei "Mein Onkel, ein großer Tierfreund, und seine Katzen leben in einer alten Mühle", durch Bindestrichte ersetzen: "Mein Onkel - ein großer Tierfreund - und seine Katzen leben in einer alten Mühle". Ich habe diesen "Trick" schon oft benutzt, um mich aus solchen Situationen zu mogeln...

Comment: Das sogenannte „[Oxford Comma](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/QAoxfordcomma.htm)“ oder „Serial Comma“ wird übrigens (laut [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)) nur im Amerikanischen Englisch, nicht aber im Britischen Englisch verwendet: „It is used less often in British English, where it is standard usage to leave it out.“

Comment: @Clemens Gut zu wissen. Ich finde es aber in jedem Fall sinnvoll für solche Zwecke, auch wenn natürlich der Satz spätestens in der gesprochenen Sprache umgestellt werden sollte.

Comment: @polemon: Ja, würde ich auch (allerdings mit [Gedankenstrichen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbgeviertstrich#Gedankenstrich), nicht Bindestrichen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meiner Meinung nach gilt hier einfach die erste Regel: Vor einem „und“, das Teile einer Aufzählung abgrenzt, steht kein Komma. Mehrdeutigkeit lässt sich nie komplett ausschließen; im Zweifelsfall sollte man den Satz umformulieren.

Answer (score 4):

Das ist definitiv falsch, egal ob Maria und Peter die Eltern sind oder nicht:

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, Maria, und Peter.

---

Aus diesem Satz kann man zweiflesfrei schließen, dass Maria und Peter nicht mit den Eltern identisch sind:

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, sowie Maria und Peter.

---

Das hier ist doppelt gemoppelt. Wenn du schon sagst, dass Maria deine Mutter und Peter dein Vater ist, und wenn du den beiden das Buch widmest, wozu es dann zusätzlich noch den Eltern widmen?

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, meiner Mutter Maria und meinem Vater Peter.

Dieser Satz kann ohne Informationsverlust wie folgt vereinfacht werden:

> Ich widme dieses Buch meiner Mutter Maria und meinem Vater Peter.

---

Aber auch diese Variante stellt klar, dass Maria und Peter jene Eltern sind, denen das Buch gewidmet wird, denn in "*X* und *Y*, *Z*" kann Z kein Bestandteil der Aufzählung sein. Die Aufzählung endet bei Y (Peter). Z, hier im Plural, beschreibt die beiden Elemente der Aufzähung näher:

> Ich widme dieses Buch Maria und Peter, meinen Eltern.

---

Wenn man klarstellen möchte, dass Maria und Peter nicht die Eltern sind (das Buch also vier Personen gewidmet sein soll), dann würde auch das funktionieren:

> Ich widme dieses Buch Maria, meinen Eltern und Peter.

Comment: Gute Antwort! Nur die letzte Version würde ich auf keinen Fall empfehlen. Die Eltern dazwischenzuschieben ist kein guter Stil, auch wenn es grammatikalisch korrekt ist. Besser: "Maria, Peter und meinen Eltern".

Answer (score 2):

Es ist anzunehmen, dass der Autor aller drei Sätze weiß, was er meint: Sind Maria und Peter seine Eltern oder zwei zusätzliche Personen?

Wenn Maria und Peter die Eltern des Autors sind, kann man das Problem umgehen, indem man die Reihenfolge ändert: "Ich widme dieses Buch Maria und Peter, meinen Eltern." Damit ist zwar nicht ausgeschlossen, dass es sich um eine Aufzählung handelt, diese wäre aber sehr umständlich und unüblich. Man würde vielmehr schreiben "Maria, Peter und meinen Eltern". Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass das Komma hier auch nicht nötig ist, "Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern Maria und Peter." wäre also auch eine eindeutige Formulierung für diesen Fall.

Im zweiten Satz ist klar, dass Maria und Peter nicht die Eltern sind. Dieser Satz braucht kein Komma, das "sowie" ersetzt das Komma in der Aufzählung.

Beim dritten Satz ist anzumerken, dass das Objekt der Widmung im Akkusativ stehen muss, also "meiner Mutter" und "meinem Vater". Ansonsten ist er auch eindeutig: Maria und Peter sind hier die Eltern des Autors.

(Der Satz mit dem Onkel, welcher ein großer Tierfreund ist, ist natürlich eindeutig. - Ebenso eindeutig lebte der Onkel mit einem großen Tierfreund und der Katze zusammen, wenn ein Komma fehlte...)

(Meine Antwort basiert ausschließlich auf meiner persönlichen Sprachkompetenz. Von ihrer Richtigkeit bin ich jedoch überzeugt und bin gern bereit, sie im Bedarfsfalle mit Quellen zu untermauern.)

Comment: Erstmal, ja, es ist davon auszugehen. Natürlich ist es die Bedingung, dass man sowas weiß. ... Aber die entscheidene Frage hast du damit leider nicht beantwortet: Kann ich ein Komma setzen oder muss ich den Satz umformulieren?

Comment: Anzumerken ist, dass ich im dritten Satz bewusst **nicht** *meiner Mutter und meinem Vater* geschrieben habe. Ich hab hier den Satz als Zusatz oder Nachtrag gedacht, der dass Wort *Eltern* näher beschreibt. Daher denke ich, dass der grammatikalisch richtig ist, oder irre ich mich?

Comment: @Em1: Ich denke, Du irrst Dich. Es wird erst richtig, wenn Du schreibst "Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern - meine Eltern, das sind meine Mutter Maria und mein Vater Peter." Sonst funktioniert der Bezug nicht.

Comment: @Em1:  Hendrik und Alexander haben recht.  Allerdings ist das doch Dativ, nicht Akkusativ, Alexander!

Comment: Ich bin mir eigentlich auch ziemlich sicher, dass kein Komma nötig ist, wenn "Maria und Peter" die Eltern sind, und wollte schon eine Antwort in der Richtung schreiben. Aber dann habe ich mich doch entschieden, diesem Aspekt eine [eigene Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25501/eltern-als-bezugswort-f%C3%BCr-eine-enge-apposition) zu widmen.