# Kommaregeln bei doppeldeutigen Sätzen

Tags: punctuation, comma

Seit ich in meinen drei Fremdsprachen bis zu den Kommaregeln durchgedrungen bin, vermische ich die Regeln in unterschiedlichen Sprachen, sodass ich mich kaum traue ein Komma zu setzen. Die übelste Verwirrung stiften Sätze nach diesem Muster:

> Die Orangen die zum Teil verfault waren schenkte er den Kindern.

Wie muss ich das Komma setzen, um auszusagen "er verschenkte nur die zum Teil verfaulten"?

Wie muss ich das Komma setzen, wenn das teils verfault sein nur Zusatzinformation ist, er aber durchaus auch frische Orangen verschenkte?

Ich habe die Kommaregeln gelesen und interpretiere sie so, dass die Interpunktion gleich wäre, was ich nicht glauben kann.

Comment: [Diese Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/7514/2594) könnte Dich interessieren.

Comment: [Ein anderes Beispiel](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4489/1224), wo im Deutschen schlichtweg kein Komma hingehört, wo man aber im Englischen mit dem serial comma (auch Oxford Comma genannt) die Aussage des Satzes klarstellen kann.

Comment: @Em1 vielen Dank für Ihre vielen Kommakorrekturen. Ich versuche daraus zu lernen:)

Comment: Übrigens vom Gefühl her ist dieser Satz übrigens eindeutig: "Er schenkte den Kindern *genau* die Orangen, die zum Teil verfault waren" — Wobei ich einräumen muss, je nach Kontext könnte die gefühlte Eindeutigkeit auch wieder flöten gehen.

Comment: Der brave Mann denkt an sich, selbst zuletzt. Eats, shoots and leaves.

Comment: @Em1... wieso ist der Satz eindeutig? "Die Biere, die zum Teil aus Belgien kamen, schenkte er den Trinkern"... was ist denn dann damit? Gleiches Gefühl? Ausserdem, wenn man es genau nimmt, dann denke ich, dass man eine einzelne Orange selten als "zum Teil verfault" bezeichnet. Entweder "faulig" oder "angefault" oder halt "verfault". Aber das "zum Teil" impliziert schon eher, dass über die Orangen in ihrer Ganzheit geredet wird.

Comment: Also grundlegend kannst Du Dir schon mal merken, dass im Deutschen vor einem Relativsatz grundsätzlich ein Komma kommt. "Die Orangen, die ...".

Comment: @userunknown Ein Querulant kann ich nicht sein :-P Ich konnte es nicht glauben, weil ich darin eine der nützlichsten Funktionen des Kommas sehe. Aber es wird schon einen Grund geben warum unsere Vorfahren es so regelten. Ich mache mir weiter Gedanken darüber und danke für die Hilfe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doch, es ist so.
Im Deutschen gibt es nicht so etwas wie im Englischen, wo das Komma gesetzt wird, wenn es eine (unwichtige) Nebeninformation ist, beziehungsweise wo das Komma weggelassen wird, wenn es eine definierende Funktion hat (defining clause vs non-defining clause)<sup>1</sup>.

In der gesprochenen Sprache existiert das Problem sowieso. Im Englischen kann man zwar theoretisch mit einer Pause das Komma vor einem defining-clause andeuten, aber das heißt nicht, dass es dadurch klar wäre.

Deswegen (und unabhängig von der Sprache): Bei einem zweideutigen Satz umformulieren! Klarstellen, wie es gemeint ist.

> Er schenkte den Kindern die zum Teil verfaulten Orangen.
>   Er schenkte den Kindern Orangen. Einige von denen waren verfault.

Bezüglich des Kommas:

> Die Orangen, die zum Teil verfault waren, schenkte er den Kindern.

---

<sup>1</sup>Einige nette [Beispiele](http://www.e-grammar.org/relative-clauses/) für's Englische:

> The passengers who fastened their seatbelts survived. (Which passengers survived? Only the pasengers wearing the seatbelts.)
>   The passengers, who fastened their seatbelts, survived. (Because all the passengers were wearing their seatbelts, they survived.)
>
> The students who did all the exercises succeeded. (Which students succeeded? Only the students doing all the exercises.)
>   The students, who did all the exercises, succeeded. (All students succeeded. Why? Because they did all the exercises.)

Comment: Faszinierend! Kaum vorstellbar, das wir unserem Komma diese wichtige Funktion nicht gegeben haben! Ich muss das genauer studieren. Zunächst scheint es als brächte unsere Praxis nur große Nachteile!

Comment: @Ludi Sehe ich anders. Erstens ist das Deutsche hier einfacher. Setze Komma. Fertig. Im Englischen muss man überlegen, ob der Nebensatz definiert oder nicht. Darüberhinaus ist ein zweideutiger Satz in jeder Sprache für'n Arsch und sollte nicht durch Setzen oder Weglassen eines Kommas "repariert" werden. Satz umformulieren. Feddich. Ich sehe also hier nur Vorteile im Deutschen: Eindeutigkeit, Einfachheit.

Comment: @Em1 das ist natürlich ein vernünftiger Standpunkt. Aber ich frage mich ob unsere Vorfahren nicht noch andere gute Gründe hatten. Sie sind nicht für unkomplizierte, wenig penible Lösungsansätze bekannt:D

Comment: In der gesprochenen Sprache ist es doch gerade KEIN Problem. "DIE Orangen, die zum Teil verfault waren,..." vs. "Die OrANGen, die zum Teil verfault waren,..." Die Betonung macht es hier eindeutig.

Comment: @Ludi.... "große Nachteile", ja welche denn? Unsere Wirstschaft, als auch unsere Literatur kommt doch ganz gut ohne aus ;). Das Grundparadigma der Kommasetzung ist in dieser Hinsicht sehr einfach. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass es was damit zu tun hat, Verbcluster am Satzende besser zu strukturieren. "... dass der Mann, der gestern gekommen ist geschlafen hat."

Comment: @Emanuel ich habe es seit einigen Jahren für die wichtigste Funktion des Kommas gehalten, dass man so einfach differenzieren kann:The passengers who fastened their seatbelts survived. (Which passengers survived? Only the pasengers wearing the seatbelts.)
The passengers, who fastened their seatbelts, survived. (Because all the passengers were wearing their seatbelts, they survived.)  Aber auch deine Argumentation leuchtet mir ein.

Answer (score 5):

Es ist aber so. Relativsätze (und Nebensätze überhaupt) werden im Deutschen immer durch Komma abgetrennt, unabhängig davon, ob sie nur Hintergrundinformationen geben oder eine Einschränkung enthalten.

Der Beispielsatz wird daher immer folgendermaßen interpungiert:

> Die Orangen, die zum Teil verfault waren, schenkte er den Kindern.