# "Eltern" als Bezugswort für eine enge Apposition

Tags: punctuation, comma, apposition

Laut [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Enge-11481) können Personennamen als Appositionen zu Verwandschaftsbezeichnungen verwendet werden:

> der Gemüsegarten meines Onkels Anton

Ich sehe keinen Grund, warum das nicht auch im Plural funktionieren sollte:

> der Gemüsegarten meiner Tanten Helga und Erna

Frage: ist das Wort *Eltern* eine Verwandschaftsbezeichnung in diesem Sinne? Könnte ich also auch analog schreiben

> der Gemüsegarten meiner Eltern Maria und Peter

oder auch (um das [Beispiel](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/komma-vor-und-bei-aufz%C3%A4hlungen-mit-mehrdeutigkeit) aufzugreifen, das diese Frage motiviert hat):

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern Maria und Peter.

Ich meine ja, aber man könnte auch argumentieren, dass "meine Eltern" schon für sich alleine eine identifizierende Bezeichnung ist, es also im Gegensatz zu "Onkel Alfred" nicht der zusätzlichen Angabe des Namens bedarf und man deshalb *Eltern* nicht wie *Onkel* oder *Tante* behandeln darf.

Und wenn es möglich ist: geht das auch mit Vor- und Familienname? [Hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=q2m7CQAAQBAJ&pg=PT3&lpg=PT3&dq=%22Ich%20widme%20*%20meinen%20Eltern%22&source=bl&ots=AhNepvlfQf&sig=NNyXjsMKFs4bWdPlgywwvObBtEE&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Ich%20widme%20*%20meinen%20Eltern%22&f=false) findet sich ein reales Beispiel nach dem Muster

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern Maria und Peter Schmidt.

und für mich sieht das ok aus. Wie wäre es bei verschiedenen Familiennamen?

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern Maria Müller und Peter Schmidt.

Eine Zusatzfrage: In allen diesen Fällen wäre es auch möglich, die Namen als Nachtrag aufzufassen und durch ein Komma abzutrennen, also z.B.

> Ich widme dieses Buch meinen Eltern, Maria Müller und Peter Schmidt.

Was spricht für die eine oder andere Variante?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich sehe keinen Grund, weshalb

> meine Eltern [*Name* und *Name*]

anders funktionieren sollte als als andere Konstruktionen des Musters

> [*Possesivpronomen]*[*Beziehung*][*Name(n)*]

(wobei [*Beziehung*] keinesfalls auf eine Verwandschaftsbeziehung beschränkt sein muss.)

Die Argumentation, dass Eltern eindeutiger seien als ein Onkel ist nicht zwingend: auch wer nur einen Onkel hat darf diesen per Apposition näher benennen, aus  der Formulierung "Onkel Alfred" kann man nicht auf die Existenz anderer Onkel schließen.

Auf die Abtrennung mit Komma würde ich verzichten, da sonst die Interpretation als Aufzählung (statt Nachtrag /Einschub) möglich wird, vor allem durch das *und* zwischen den Namen.