# Gehört nach einem eingeschobenen Nebensatz ein Komma?

Tags: punctuation, comma, subordinate-clause

> So stellen die Leute sicher, *dass ihr Auto nicht geklaut wird*, und
>   sie immer einen Parkplatz haben.

Soweit ich das beurteilen kann, gehört nach dem *wird* ein Komma. Stimmt das?

Comment: I think here the discussions/questions are only in English - so it would be more chances to get the answer.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/komma-vor-und-bei-aufz%C3%A4hlungen-mit-mehrdeutigkeit

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis No, this is not so. The languages in this forum are both English and German, both have the same status.

Comment: Ok, strange, but understood. Other language forums like http://japanese.stackexchange.com or http://russian.stackexchange.com - the questions and answers are  mainly in English.. I mean it is better to understand to non German language speakers. I found the answer [here](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in).

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis: But then languages are best learnt in immersion and German questions provide another opportunity to learn. Anyway, if you want to discuss further, please take this to [meta] or chat.

Comment: Das ist kein eingeschobener Nebensatz, sondern ein beigeordneter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hier liegt aber kein eingeschobener Nebensatz vor: Wenn man den Teil zwischen den Kommas weglässt, bleibt kein kompletter Satz übrig.

Also gehört *dass* zu beiden Auswirkungen, und *und* ist eine normale Aufzählung, vor der das Komma nicht stehen darf.

Comment: [Das Komma ist da völlig richtig. (Siehe 11.)](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K111). Und es handelt sich nebenbei bemerkt um einen Objektsatz.